# Tumblr won't autoplay vine embed

Tags: vine

My Tumblr wont autoplay vine embeds, I'm not sure what to do about this.

http://kyliejenner69.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the code they provide for the embed, it includes a script.

(*you shouldn't include it for every one - if you have multiple vines in your page*)

Adding it once in your page should fix the issue.

```
<script src="https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js"></script>
```